# How can I optimize a pipeline in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

How can I optimize a pipeline in Azure DevOps that contains a plugin, so that, when that plugin was modified, the pipeline to be built automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers). You simply need to define trigger according to your need. Be aware that you have described there yaml and classic pipelines.